# Simplify nested loops and conditions in replacing string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need assistance to simplify my code.
Code should check if there is only two letters to be replace then break the for loop:

```
word = "hesitation"
for i in word:
    if i == 'a':
        new_word = word.replace(i, '@')
        for x in new_word:
            if x == 'o':
                new_word1 = new_word.replace(x, '0')
                for n in new_word1:
                    if n == 's':
                        new_word2 = new_word1.replace(n, '$')
                        print new_word2
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all instead of nested loops you can also do this in the following manner:

```
word = "hesitation"
for i in word:
    if i == 'a':
        word = word.replace(i, '@')
for x in word:
    if x == 'o':
        word = word.replace(x, '0')
for n in word:
    if n == 's':
        word = word.replace(n, '$')
print word
```

The above code is more efficient both time and space wise.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This will replace *all* occurrences of each character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` with the optional argument `maxreplace` that specifies the max replace. When given, the If the first `maxreplace` occurrences are replaced:

```
word = "hesitation"
a = word.replace('a', '@', 1)
b = a.replace('o', '0', 1)
c = b.replace('s', '$', 1)
# c = he$it@ti0n
```

Comment: can `word` be used instead of a, b, c to replace in place

Comment: @TarunGupta You should assign the result, `replace` returns a new string and doesn't modify it in-place.

Comment: I am suggesting to store the return string of replace every time in the variable `word` only instead of creating three more variables.